# Reading Embedded controller memory

Tags: embedded

I have a windows7 machine with an Embedded Controller (EC) on its mother board. EC works according to ACPI  protocol. EC stores temperature and fan speed values in its memory. I am trying to access these values from the EC memory.

Please let me know if the OpenHardWareMonitor(http://openhardwaremonitor.org/), which uses WinRing0 and WMI, can be used to read the EC memory. If not, please suggest the procedure to read EC memory.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface

Comment: On Linux, you just need to use `sensors` package and pseudo-files like `/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`; did you try to compile and use your OpenHardwareMonitor?

Comment: This question is not exactly the same, but I think that it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032807/c-code-for-cpu-load-and-cpu-temperature